# Regex that matches specific word and then only x numbers after that without dirty characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex that turns this

```
FOOAB ABC98.24-?.3276
```

into this

```
ABC98243276
```

A specific word (like "ABC" or like "HOUSE" but not only the single characters of the word itself) and, immediately after that, 8 numbers and only the numbers (without dirty characters like ?-:;#).

Is that possible? Can you help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: What is *dirty character*, please? Is it *dot* only? If not, shall we turn `FOO ABC123?.+-*/456([bar: 78^999])` into `ABC12345678`?

Comment: Dirty characters can be everything. I want only the numbers. So is correct what you just wrote.

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this question? I think it's a pretty tough regex...

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex?

Comment: It's difficult to explain. I just prefer the regex in this project i'm working on if I can. If i could do this with code I would do it in no time...

Comment: All that a regex does is identify specific parts of a string - not much differently than doing it without a regex in this case. You still need to write code that actually creates the desired string from the result that the regexp, because a regex can't do that. It would probably be much simpler easier to read and maintain code that does this without an regex. Also, you need to tell us programming language you are using, because A) there is no standardized regex syntax (each regex library has differences) and B) in order to write the code that creates the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if I have understood your problem properly but with PHP I have tried something.

```
$string = "FOO ABC98.24-?.3276";
echo $string."<br/>";
$string = str_replace(str_split('/:.-*?"<>|'), '', $string);
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, " ") + 1);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Yes but that's not a regular expression. It works but it's not what I'm looking for. Thank you anyway.